# solving random walk problem with law of total probability

Tags: probability

A drunk man goes right with probability $P$ and left with probability $1-p$
. What's the probability  he will get to $-1$ before getting to $2$ ? (The drunk man starts at 0)

I tried to solve it with law of total probability however my answer is wrong from some reason .

My answer:
Let $P(X)$ be the location of the drunk man
.There are only 2 cases, one where he goes left and one where he goes right .

$P(X=-1)=P(X=-1|Left)P(Left)+P(X=-1|Right)P(Right)$

$P(X=-1|Left)P(Left) =1-p $

$P(X-1|Right)P(Right)=p(1-p)P(X=-1)$ because he goes right with probability $p$ and in order to get to $-1$ he has to go left ($1-p$) and then we are at the starter point $P(X=-1)$

Comment: I assume we start at location 0.  What is your definition of $X$ and what is the meaning of the sentence "Let $P[X=-1]$ the point where he got $-1$"?  (A probability is not a point where someone gets something)

Comment: Yes we start at 0 .
X is location .
$P(x=-1)$ the location$ -1$ .
I will edit the post to clarify .

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "X is location."  I assume $X$ is supposed to be a random variable.  Is it a random location?  At what time?  Do you really mean that $X_t$ is the location at time $t \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$?

Comment: X is a random variable that represents the first time the drunk man visits a point x.

Comment: The drunk man moves.  So, how is $X$ defined as "the location."  The location at what time?

Comment: Can I give you better notation with which you can solve the problem? Are you willing to receive that?

Comment: Yes if possible.

Comment: I think you mean to say that $X_t$ is a random variable that represents the man's location at time $t$.  Your equations should relate $X_{t+1}$ to $X_t.$

Comment: Well Lulu gives an answer below.  If you define $A$ as the event that we get to $-1$ before $2$, and if we use $X_t$ as defined above, her notation is $p(i) = P[A|X_0=i]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume he is starting at $0$.

Method I:  Geometric Series

The winning paths all have the form $\gamma_n=(RL)^nL$ for $n\in \{0,1,2,\cdots \}$.
(Here, of course, $R$ denotes a step to the right and $L$ denotes a step to the left.  I am reading the path from left to right, but it's easy to rewrite if you prefer the other convention). The probability that he follows $\gamma_n$ is $(p(1-p))^n(1-p)$

We easily compute the answer to be $$(1-p)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (p(1-p))^n=\boxed {\frac {1-p}{p^2-p+1}}$$

Note:  that this method only works so easily because you have a very small number of states to consider.

A method which extends more easily to situations with more states is:

Method II:  Recursion

There are only a few states to consider, according which position the drunk occupies.  For $i\in \{-1,0,1,2\}$ we let $P(i)$ denote the probability that he gets to $-1$ before he gets to $2$ assuming he is starting at $i$.  Of course $P(-1)=1$ and $P(2)=0$.  The answer we want is $P(0)$.

We remark that $$P(0)= (1-p)\times 1 +p\times P(1)$$
and $$P(1)=p\times 0 + (1-p)\times P(0)=(1-p)\times P(0)$$

It follows that $$P(0)=(1-p)+p(1-p)P(0)$$ which implies $$P(0)=\boxed {\frac {1-p}{p^2-p+1}}$$

Sanity checks: if $p=0$ this is $1$.  If $p=1$ this is $0$.  A little more work shows that $0≤P(0)≤1$ for $0≤p≤1$.

Comment: Why is $P(0)$ the answer . isn't it the probability he gets to point $0$ ?

Comment: I understood the question to be asking "Assume the drunk starts at $0$ and moves right or left with probabilities as stated.  What is the probability that he gets to $-1$ before getting to $2$?".  Did you mean something else?

Comment: You understood correctly ,but I cant seem to understand how is $P(0)$ related to the answer . Aren't we seeking for $P(-1)$?

Comment: Again, $P(i)$ is defined to be the probability that our drunk gets to $-1$ before getting to $2$, assuming he starts at point $i$.  Since you are assuming he is starting at point $0$ you are asking about $P(0)$.

Comment: You can do it by Geometric Series, since the winning paths all have the form $(RL)^nL$ for some $n$.  I'm not a fan of that method because it really doesn't work if you have more states, but it's a good exercise to check that it works here.

Comment: Note:  I added the argument by Geometric Series.